# Some syntax sugar in TypeScript for case when value is even with type?

Tags: typescript

Is there some syntax sugar in TypeScript allows to initialize `value` without duplicating the expression in the right of `type Type =`? (Yes, semicolon must be replaced with commas)

```js
type Type = {
    foo: "alpha";
    bravo: "bravo";
};

const value: Type = {
    foo: "alpha",
    bravo: "bravo"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is infer the type from the expression, `typeof` is your friend:

```
const value = {
    foo: "alpha",
    bravo: "bravo"
};
type Type = typeof value;
```

That will give you a type like:

```
type Type = {
    foo: string;
    bravo: string;
};
```

If you need to infer the every value type as a literal you can do something like:

```
const value = {
    foo: "alpha",
    bravo: "bravo"
} as const;

type Type = typeof value;
```

Now `Type` will be:

```
type Type = {
    readonly foo: "alpha";
    readonly bravo: "bravo";
};
```

If you don't want the properties as `readonly` you can do:

```
const value = {
    foo: "alpha" as const,
    bravo: "bravo" as const
};

type Type = typeof value;
```

And `Type` will be:

```
type Type = {
    foo: "alpha";
    bravo: "bravo";
};
```

Comment: VERY HIGH quality answer! Thank you very much!